# Existence of the limit of the norm of a function $h_n = \sqrt{n} \chi_{(0,1/n)}$ in $L^2(0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Consider the sequence $h_n = \sqrt{n} \chi_{(0,1/n)}$ in $L^2(0,1)$. Then $||h_n|| = 1$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$. But what can we say about the limit as $n\to \infty$ of the norm of $h_n$? Does it or does it not exist? What are criteria for the existence of the limit of a norm of a function in general?

Comment: we can say that the norm of $h_n$ converges to $1$

Comment: Since $\|h_n\|_2 = 1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N},$ then $h_n$ converges to $h = 1$ in the norm $\|\cdot\|_2.$ Just view the sequence $(\|h_n\|_2)_{n\geq 1}$ as a sequence of numbers $1.$

Comment: As  the norm is continuous, though, can't we bring the limit inside the norm and then when we take the limit on $h_n$ It blows up (with respect to the characteristic function)? That is $$\lim_{n\to \infty} ||h_n|| = ||\lim_{n\to \infty} h_n|| = \text{Does not exist?}$$

Comment: No you cant always..you need some theorems for this,like Lebesgue Dominated Convergence theorem for instance...And also in this example we have that $h_n \rightarrow 0$ thus we cannot interchange limits and norms.

Comment: You can't even do this in $\mathbb{R}$. Take $x_n = 1$ if $n$ is odd and $-1$ if $n$ is even. Then $|x_n|$ converges, but $(x_n)$ does not. What you are asking for is something akin to this in $L^2(0,1)$

Comment: I don't understand the question. The sequence in question is $1,1,1,\dots$ You're asking if $1,1,1,\dots$ has a limit?

Comment: @MariosGretsas Can you clarify if we have norm convergence, as saz's answer below is in conflict with yours?

Comment: I don't understand your question @eurocoder  ..what does conflict with mine?

Comment: You say the norm of $h_n$ converges to $1$ but saz seems to be saying the norm does not converge to its limit?

Comment: @eurocoder the answerer  wrote  $||h_n|| \rightarrow 1$.But $||\lim h_n||=||0||=1 \neq 1$and we arrive  to the point where i said that we cannot interchange  limits and norms becuase $h_n \rightarrow 0$ thus the integral-norm of the limit $0$ is $0$.I ment the same with the answerer although he stated it better than me and more completely..The general idea is that we cannot interchange always limits and norms(in this case integrals).We must have some conditions to do that.

Comment: Yes $||h_n|| \to 1$ but the only possible limit for the sequence in $L^2$ is $0$. Therefore, the sequence $h_n$ does not converge in $L^2$, that is, it does not converge when using the $L^2$ norm. However in your first comment you said the sequence converges in $L^2$ to the value $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Riesz-Fischer theorem is a useful tool to identify (candidates for) $L^2$-limits:

> Let $h_n$ be a sequence such that $h_n \to h$ in $L^2$. Then there exists a subsequennce $h_{n_k}$ such that $h_{n_k} \to h$ almost everywhere as $k \to \infty$.

Since $h_n = \sqrt{n} \chi_{(0,/1n)}$ converges pointwise to $0$ on the interval $(0,1)$, we find that $h := 0$ is the only candidate for the $L^2$-limit. However,

$$\|h\|_{L^2} = 0 \neq 1 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \|h_n\|_{L^2},$$

and therefore $h_n$ does **not** converge to $h$ in $L^2$.

This shows that the sequence $(h_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ does not converge in $L^2$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a bounded sequence $\{h_n\}$ in $L^2$, since $L^2$ is reflexive, you can find a subsequence $\{h_{n_k}\}$ which converges weakly to some function $h$, that is
$$\int_0^1 h_{n_k}(x)g(x)\,dx\to \int_0^1 h(x)g(x)\,dx$$ for every $g\in L^2$. 
Since $\{h_{n_k}\}$ converges weakly to $h$ in $L^2$, you always have that
$$\Vert h\Vert_{L^2}\le\liminf_{k\to\infty}\Vert h_{n_k}\Vert_{L^2}$$ but in general you have strict inequality as your example shows. 
However, since $L^2$ is uniformly convex (see [uniform convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_convex_space)), if it happens that
$$\Vert h\Vert_{L^2}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\Vert h_{n_k}\Vert_{L^2},$$
then actually $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\Vert h_{n_k}-h\Vert_{L^2}.$$
So weak convergence in $L^2$ and existence of the limit of the norm is equivalent to strong convergence.